# Can you specialize an already specialized bean in CDI?

Tags: jsf, cdi

EJB Project1

```
@SessionScoped
@Named("bean")
class A
{}

@Specializes
class B extends A
{}
```

EJB Project2

```
@Specializes
class C extends B
{}
```

Web Project
In XHTML

```
#{bean.class.name}
```

is returning B

My question is can I specialize and already specialized bean in CDI? Hiding the first specialized bean in all scopes.

Answer (score 0):

[CDI JSR299 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr299/index.html) describes specialization as:

> either:
>
> - X directly specializes Y, or
> - a bean Z exists, such that X directly specializes Z and Z specializes Y

Second bullet point describes your case. And it indeed it works. See [my example](https://github.com/destin/SO-answers/tree/master/SO-can-you-specialize-an-already-specialized-bean-in-cdi).

The reason that it does not work for you is probably related to the fact that `C` class is in another project and is not detected by CDI. Maybe you forgot to add `beans.xml` file to `Project2`?